Writing Middleware in Traefik
I encountered a problem while writing the traefik middleware  specifically as follows
This is my code

type captureResponseWriter struct {
    Headers    http.Header
    StatusCode int
    Buffer     bytes.Buffer
    rw         http.ResponseWriter
}

func NewCapture(rw http.ResponseWriter) *captureResponseWriter {
    return &captureResponseWriter{
        rw:         rw,
        Headers:    http.Header{},
        StatusCode: 200,
        Buffer:     bytes.Buffer{},
    }
}

func (w *captureResponseWriter) Header() http.Header {
    return w.rw.Header()
}

func (w *captureResponseWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    w.rw.WriteHeader(w.StatusCode)
    return w.Buffer.Write(b)
}

func (w *captureResponseWriter) WriteHeader(statusCode int) {
    w.StatusCode = statusCode
    w.Headers = w.Header().Clone()
    //w.rw.WriteHeader(statusCode)
}
func (w *captureResponseWriter) Flush() {
    if f, ok := w.rw.(http.Flusher); ok {
        f.Flush()
    }
}
func (w *captureResponseWriter) Hijack() (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error) {
    if h, ok := w.rw.(http.Hijacker); ok {
        return h.Hijack()
    }
    return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("not a hijacker: %T", w.rw)
}

func (h *accessControlHandler) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    capture := NewCapture(rw)
    h.source.ServeHTTP(capture, req)
    for k, v := range capture.Headers {
        rw.Header()[k] = v
    }
    for _, rule := range h.config.Rules {
        r := NewRule(rule.Expr)

        matchRule := r.Run()
        if !matchRule {
            continue
        }
        h.logger.Infof("match rule: %s, with action %s\n", r.RawExpr, r.Action)
        switch r.Action {

        case "reject":
            content := []byte("Block by AccessControl!")
            rw.Header().Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprintf("%d", len(content)))
            rw.WriteHeader(403)
            rw.Write(content)
            // backendapi.TCPBlockIPonDomain(ip, h.domainID, rule.BlockTime, "AccessControl") // 增加
            go requestlog.SendAttackLog(req, "精准访问控制", makeAttackLogInfo(host, h.domainHost, ForwardedURL, "拦截", r.RawExpr, ""), h.domainID, h.localaddr, h.domainHost)
            return
            }
        }
    }
        h.next.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}


The connection for POST requests in the current normal response is
Close this resulted in the response content being Internal Server Error
I hope to receive a normal response from the source site
And when intercepted and returned to 403, the status code and header header were not intercepted
